# config.getInitParameter() is returning null value in JSP?

Tags: jsp

I have tried an example using JSP, in that I am trying to get initial parameter in a JSP, which is declared in web.xml. But it is returning null value.

See below my code:
Response_Config.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Response and Config Object Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Imp_response.jsp">
        User Name : <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Imp_response.jsp

```
<body>
    <%
    System.out.println("Before Redirecting");
    String uname = request.getParameter("username");
    session.setAttribute("username", uname);
    response.sendRedirect("Imp_config.jsp"); %>
</body>
```

Imp_config.jsp

```
<body>
    <%
        out.println("Welcome !... "+session.getAttribute("username"));
        String uname=config.getInitParameter("company");    
        String degree = config.getInitParameter("degree");
        System.out.println("uname = "+uname);
        System.out.println("degree = "+degree);
    %>
    <h4>Company : <%= uname %></h4><br />
    <h4>Degree : <%= degree %></h4>
</body>
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ImplicitConfig</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/Imp_config.jsp</jsp-file>

  <init-param>
  <param-name>company</param-name>
  <param-value>ABC pvt ltd</param-value>  
  </init-param>

  <init-param>  
  <param-name>degree</param-name>
  <param-value>MCA</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ImplicitConfig</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Imp_config</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

**Application Flow is: Response_Config.html --> Imp_response.jsp --> Imp_config.jsp**

When I run it as whole application, it gives following output:
In My Web page

```
Welcome !... kavi   //I have entered User Name : kavi 
Company : null
Degree : null
```

But, when I run the **Imp_config.jsp** separately it gives the following output:

```
Welcome !... null  //I know the session is null, when I run separately
Company : ABC pvt ltd
Degree : MCA
```

I don't know why it produce Null value when I run it as whole application. Please share your Ideas it will be appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like this : response.sendRedirect("Imp_config");

> In JSP, config is an implicit object of type ServletConfig.

`/Imp_config`, your servlet mapping url that allow to jsp file declare as servlet.

Comment: Thanks @Gurkan Yesilyurt

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `action="Imp_response.jsp"`
try `action="Imp_response"`
As you need to be precise as Java won't consider both as same.